# How would you test a service that uses a JpaRepository with Spock and in memory database?

Tags: rest, spring-boot, h2, spock

I am using Spock to test a small rest application that uses a JpaRepository but I seem to be having trouble to use an in memory database in my test. I admit that I am mostly following exaples, I still don't really understand all that is going on so any help would be appreciated and any explanation as a bonus would be greatly welcomed.

This is what I have so far.
My controller:

```
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collection;

import static org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod.GET;
import static org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod.POST;

@RestController
@RequestMapping("facilities")
public class FacilityController {

    private IFacilityService facilityService;

    @Autowired
    public FacilityController(IFacilityService facilityService) {
        this.facilityService = facilityService;
    }

    @RequestMapping(path = "list", method = GET)
    public ResponseEntity<Collection<Facility>> list() {
        Collection<Facility> facilities = new ArrayList<>();

        facilityService.getFacilities().forEach(facilities::add);

        return ResponseEntity.ok().body(facilities);
    }

    @RequestMapping(path = "add", method = POST)
    public ResponseEntity<?> add(@RequestBody FacilityDto facilityDto) {
        Facility facility = facilityService.add(facilityDto);

        return ResponseEntity.ok().body(facility);
    }
}
```

The service it is using

```
import com.futsaltime.database.repositories.IFacilityRepository;
import com.futsaltime.mappers.FacilityMapper;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

@Service
public class FacilityService implements IFacilityService {

    private IFacilityRepository facilityRepository;

    @Autowired
    public FacilityService(IFacilityRepository facilityRepository) {
        this.facilityRepository = facilityRepository;
    }

    @Override
    public Iterable<Facility> getFacilities() {
        return facilityRepository.findAll();
    }

    @Override
    public Facility add(FacilityDto facilityDto) {
        Facility facility = FacilityMapper.toModel(facilityDto);

        return facilityRepository.save(facility);
    }
}
```

The repository

```
@Transactional
public interface IFacilityRepository extends CrudRepository<Facility, Long> {

    Collection<Facility> findAllByFacilityName(String facilityName);
}
```

The application.yml

```
server:
  port: 8000

endpoints:
  enabled: true
  sensitive: false

spring:
  datasource: # DataSource settings: set here your own configurations for the database
    url: jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/futsaltime
    type: com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource
    username: root
    password: root
    testWhileIdle: true # Keep the connection alive if idle for a long time (needed in production)
    validationQuery: SELECT 1
  jpa:
    show-sql: true
    hibernate:
      ddl-auto: create
    # Use spring.jpa.properties.* for Hibernate native properties (the prefix is stripped before adding them to the entity manager)
    properties:
      hibernate:
        dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL57Dialect # To force the engine to InnoDB
        format_sql: true
```

And the test in question

```
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired
import org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.DataJpaTest
import org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTest
import org.springframework.test.context.ContextConfiguration
import spock.lang.Specification

@ContextConfiguration
@SpringBootTest
@DataJpaTest
class FacilityServiceTest extends Specification {

    FacilityService facilityService

    @Autowired
    IFacilityRepository facilityRepository;

    def setup() {
        facilityService = new FacilityService(facilityRepository)
    }

    def "retrieves all the facilities saved in the database"() {
        given:


        when:
        def result = facilityService.getFacilities()

        then:
        result.isEmpty()
    }
}
```

I read that *@ContextConfiguration* is required to be able to scan the classes to use in *Autowiring* (is this true) and the SpringBootTest to pick the applications.yml in the test folder. I have one there that sets up an in memory H2 database but I am not sure if that is needed when I use *@DataJpaTest*.

If I run the test the repository is not autowired and the service is created with a null so I get a NPE. 
Can someone help point out what I am missing or point me to a guide or even some coments about the annotations and if they are correctly used?

Comment: If you are using spock 1.1 then you don't need to add `@ContextConfiguration` when `@SpringBootTest` is used. You need to annotate your repository with `@Repository`. And you might want to inject the `FacilityService` instead of constructing it in the test.

Comment: @LeonardBrünings I added the repository annotation and tried to autowire the service instead of using the setup method but still the same. Maybe I am doing something more fundamental wrong.

Comment: Do you have both spock-core and spock-spring 1.1 in the classpath?

Comment: No, I only have org.spockframework:spock-core:1.1-groovy-2.4. Ok I will ry that